# How to make my application as default launcher

Tags: android, sms, default

I've developed and application for sending/receiving SMS messages.

I want to make my application as default for reading messages whenever message is received and is viewed from the notification area.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The only thing you can adjust is the priority of getting the broadcast. If your priority is high enough it will receive the SMS broadcast before the native message app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can receive the SMS and send it, but you can not stop other apps from receiving SMS. At least not without root.
The user has to choose which SMS-App he is using, and he needs to manually disable notifications from the default SMS-App.
Also you need to implement your own notifications if you want them to be shown on receiving sms.

Comment: So what i need to do is implement my own notification and when the user clicks on that notification it should redirect to my application?

Comment: How to work with notifications can be read here http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html